# How to Customize Category URL?

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

Regarding Customize Category Url like :

```
storename.com\category_id+category_name+category_attribute
```

> I read before :  "If you have a small amount of customization
>   necessary, the URL rewrite functionality can be a consideration.Beyond
>   that, any custom URL structure will need a custom router. Magento 2
>   makes it very easy to configure a custom router for your application"
>   JOSEPH MAXWELL

So I should use Router Or Url Rewrite in this case ?